# How to use MediaQuery in bottom padding in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use media query in bottom padding so that the soft keyboard won’t cover the form on the modal bottomsheet but I am getting an invalid constant value error and a red line from the media Query. This is what I typed:

`padding: const EdgeInsets.only( top: 10, left: 10, right: 10, bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom + 10),`

Answer (score 3):

Remove the const keyword will fix the error...as getting a value from MediaQuery.of(context) you can't use a constant keyword.

e.g.

```
 padding: EdgeInsets.only( top: 10, left: 10, right: 10, bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom + 10),
```

Comment: thank you so much. I did not notice there was a const in the padding.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the const keyword. Because, `MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom + 10)` is not static. It is a dynamic value. A dynamic value cannot be const.

you need to write:

```
padding: EdgeInsets.only( top: 10, left: 10, right: 10, bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom + 10)
```